# Simple Facebook PHP Auth and Call to retrieve a pages total likes

Tags: php, facebook

Much of the information I'm reading about Facebook API calls is now outdated and it's driving me nuts trying to find a working example I can pull apart.

All I'm looking for is a simple PHP script to authenticate and get a count of likes for a specified Facebook page URL.

I believe this is the depricated function I want to replicate:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=https://www.facebook.com/MyExampleFacebookPage
```

If anyone has a simple, efficient script or can point me to towards an up-to-date guide I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: The API call as shown above is not deprecated (although to request information about Facebook pages, usually simply the page name or id is used, and not the full HTTP URL – `/MyExampleFacebookPage`); but with a more current API version you need to explicitly request the fields you want returned. And if the page itself is public (not access restricted in any way), you can simply use an app access token to request this information (so no need to implement login.)

Comment: That's good to know! Thanks! Do you by chance have a link to any documentation on how to 'explicitly request the fields you want returned'?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, section titled “Declarative Fields” / https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s a lot easier with the Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/MyExampleFacebookPage?fields=name,likes&access_token=[App-ID]|[App-Secret]
```

If the page is not restricted by age or location, you can just use an App Access Token. More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/